# Will apps developed on Office 365 work on a hosted SharePoint solution?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-365

I can't find any information - or I'm not searching the right terms, but I'm trying to find out if apps developed on an Office 365 site will also work with a hosted SharePoint solution?

In the end, I will be developing solely for a hosted solution but while I wait for the actual equipment to host it locally for development I'd like to get started. I might be a bit confused on exactly how the App Model works, so any further explanation would be excellent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you develop SharePoint Apps you have 3 hosting options:

- SharePoint Hosted Apps: All the code is JavaScript running in the browser. These will work the same in Office 365 <=> On-premises. Note the code can only do what both it and the current user is allowed to do.
- Provider Hosted Apps: The code is running a web server you as developer is responsible for (can be Azure). The setup for On-premises is a bit harder than for Office 365, but will work for both. The code has the possibility to run with it's own rights regardless of the current user.
- Auto hosted Apps: Development/possibilities is the same as for Provider Hosted Apps, but Office 365 automatically provisions the app in Azure when installed. This will not work On-premises.

Answer (score 0):

In office 365 you can get the NAPA app and do the development of your apps actually in this app.

Once you get your on premises equipment for developing apps, you can easily create SharePoint hosted apps where you basically copy paste in the JavaScript code from your NAPA app! After that, you will have an app that will be installable on just about any SP 2013 environment.

To get you up and running, search for NAPA and SharePoint hosted apps